# Excel VBA. Convert a list of cells to Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to return ranges of cells with conditional formatting as a string. I've managed to create a list of cells with the conditional formatting with the following code.

```
    Set Data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For Each Cell In Data
        If Cell.FormatConditions.Count > 0 Then
            If (Not ConditionallyFormattedCellsArray) = -1 Then: ReDim ConditionallyFormattedCellsArray(0)
            If (ConditionallyFormattedCellsArray(UBound(ConditionallyFormattedCellsArray)) <> "") Then: ReDim Preserve ConditionallyFormattedCellsArray(UBound(ConditionallyFormattedCellsArray) + 1)
            ConditionallyFormattedCellsArray(UBound(ConditionallyFormattedCellsArray)) = Cell.Address
        End If
    Next Cell
```

In my situation there could be one, or multiple different ranges of data with conditional formatting, and I would like to reduce all of those individual cells down to those ranges.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how to achieve your result by creating a `Union` of all the cells you find in a given range that have conditional formatting.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()
    Dim cfCells As Range
    Dim checkCell As Range
    For Each checkCell In Sheet1.UsedRange
        If checkCell.FormatConditions.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print checkCell.Address
            If cfCells Is Nothing Then
                Set cfCells = checkCell
            Else
                Set cfCells = Union(cfCells, checkCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next checkCell

    Dim allCFCells As String
    If cfCells Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "no conditionally formatted cells found in range " & Sheet1.UsedRange.Address
    Else
        allCFCells = cfCells.Address
        Debug.Print "conditionally formatted cells: " & allCFCells
    End If
End Sub
```